# Ruby on Rails: Anything but numbers in validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to validate a text input. I have noticed though that it fails if there are any spaces in the text field.

```
validates_format_of :role, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"
```

What do I need to change to allow spaces? Thanks

Update:

Changed question to anything but numbers, as I need to allow special characters in the text field.

Comment: This is more of regex problem. You can allow spaces like this /\A[a-zA-Z _]+\z/. Note this is not a solution but a pointer on how you do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a space to the characters you are matching (at the moment `a-z` and `A-Z`). Hence

```
/\A[a-zA-Z ]+\Z/
```

Note that `\s` will match *any* whitespace character (including tabs and newlines).

**Update**

To allow everything but numbers, you can use a "negated character class", which is made by putting a caret `^` at the start of the square brackets:

```
/\A[^0-9]+\Z/
```

or, since `\d` (for "digit") is equivalent to `[0-9]`,

```
/\A[^\d]+\Z/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have just noticed I actually need everything but numbers, how would I go about that? So A-Z, a-z, \s and special characters like ()*&^. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer. You should edit your question to reflect this change.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby regex supports `\s` as a whitespace character. So you should be able to add that to your character class.

```
:with => /\A[a-zA-Z\s]+\z/
```

Proof:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z\s]+\z/ =~ 'hello world' #=> true
/\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/   =~ 'hello world' #=> false
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have just noticed I actually need everything but numbers, how would I go about that? So A-Z, a-z, \s and special characters like ()*&^. Thanks

Comment: @Alex Wayne why is the \A required? Testing this with rubular seems to fail with "test9" for example.

Comment: `\A` just signifies the start of the string, an anchor.  `"test9"` would fail because the regex does not allow any numbers.